# rails models association scenario

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, models, single-table-inheritance

users => has_many :contacts, :through => :user_contacts
contacts => has_many :users, :through => :user_contacts

profiles

now for profiles, there's a single profile for each user but there are two ways to access it, based on the url. There's a public url and a private url. A public url belongs to a user but the private url belongs to a contact (i.e assigned to the contact as a private url to the profile of the user to which that contact belongs). I'm confused how to treat profiles association with user and contacts in this scenario.

should i use STI for profiles like class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base, class PublicProfile < Profile, class PrivateProfile < Profile

but if that's valid, how do i manage the associations here?

Answer (score 0):

what about simply having a single url type and differentiating with a type in the table. Then you can have the relationships for each TYPE of url with something along the lines of:

```
belongs_to :private_url, :class_name => "Profiles", :conditions => "type = 0"
belongs_to :public_url, :class_name => "Profiles", :conditions => "type = 1"
```

This would significantly "simplify" your assciations you have to manage. It's not the whole answer I don't think but perhaps if you can make it work this simplifies things enough that the problem you have becomes simpler to address.

I may have the exact syntax above incorrect but you should get the gist of what I'm suggesting...